# Representing Charts as map Markers - HERE Maps

Tags: here-api

I am using heremaps Javascript library as a base for my mapping development. The use case is to display a **pie-chart** as markers on map.

Is there a simple way to do this. Can I pick here charting library "Data Lens" and represent charts created through them as map markers.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker supports SVG ([example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers)) so if Pie charts are created using SVG then this should be possible. The graphs from Data Lens are usually embedded using Iframe, you could embed the iFrame in the Infobubble with the Marker but using the Chart as a marker itself might not be possible.

Comment: Thanks Jitin. Implemented a svg pie-chart and used it as DomMarker in the map. worked like a charm